# CSS fixed left, fluid right, centered within fixed width

Tags: html, css, width, fixed, fluid

I created an image of what i would like to create using CSS. I also made a small setup in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9Yda/1/).

The problem is that i can create everyting, except for the fluid column on the right. I am using it to show images in a slideshow, and i would like them to appear from the right of the screen and dissapear on the left "behind" content 1.

I tried absolute, relative and fixed positioning. But the result is either losing the centered left positioning of content 1 or not having a fluid column up to the right of column 2.

[image]

Comment: Do you want the slider to 'exist' outside of container B, so that your normal content will fit inside contanier B, but the slider images go right up to the edge of your screen?

Comment: Yes, it's a parallax slideshow. I want to content to be shown from the right side of the screen and slide all the way to the left (right of content 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/a9Yda/4/) what you were looking for?

I added a fixed position and min width to the right div which seems to have achieved the effect you were looking for.

Comment: This IS the code! Thanks, i just tested it in Opera, FF, Chrome, Safari and Iexplorer 8,9,10 and it all works, even with Parallax. So basically i should have used fixed and min-width. Thanks for the help! I accepted and upvoted your answer.

Comment: I found that Safari on the iPad and Iexplorer 9 on Win 7, don't need the margin. Hence the layout looks mixed upin both browsers. I am also missing a vertical scrollbar in all browsers. Do you perhaps know a solution to fix it. I can work with several classes for eac browser, but that wouldn't solve the scrolling. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fixed to absolute solved the scrolling issue cross-browser. I am now using margin:0 for iexplorer only to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use width:100% to fill the whole screen, http://jsfiddle.net/a9Yda/2/

Comment: Yes, but then i would loose the centered and fixed position.